# Appending a value to an AD Group Object

Tags: powershell

I'm rather new to Powershell, but I have been trying to pull a list of sAMAccountNames from an AD Group to export to a CSV file. I do the following to do so:

`Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "group name" -Recursive | Select-Object SamAccountName | Export-Csv c:\"file location`

I get the list of account usernames that I want, however, I'm not familiar enough to then append our domain to create an email list from this. I tried something similar to the following within the script:

`| Select-Object SamAccountName | ForEach-Object { $_ + '@domain.net'} |`

`| Select-Object SamAccountName | ForEach-Object { $SamAccountName + '@domain.net} |`

I know I need to somehow pull the object as a variable to then append the new string value, just not sure how. Any tips or points of clarification are appreciated.

Comment: Please, format the question for proper reading.

Comment: What does this have to do with vb.net? Please edit your question and remove this tag.

Answer (score 0):

Following script uses a string to look up all group members. Looks up each samAccountName and appends the @domain.com to it.

**CODE**

```
(Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "YourGroupHere" -Recursive | select-object samAccountName).samAccountName | ForEach-Object { "$_@domain.com" } | Export-Csv C:\fileLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "Group" -Recursive |
    Select-Object samAccountName,@{n='UpdatedName';e={"{0}@domain.com" -f $_.SamAccountName } } |
        Export-Csv -Path file.csv -NoType
```

The result is `file.csv` that contains two columns, `SamAccountName` and `UpdatedName`.

This relies on a calculated property (syntax `@{n='property';e={value}}`) within `Select-Object`. The good thing about calculated properties is the expression applies against each item piped into `Select-Object`. This easily allows you to return `SamAccountName` and your new value as a PowerShell custom object that can be exported to a CSV. Without properties, your CSV export will only contain string lengths.